# Execute Process Task to download from SFTP

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ssis

I am wondering if anyone knows how to access an SFTP site to download a file through Visual Studio. I have the following code written in a text file:

```
option confirm off
open sftp://username:password@placeineedtogo
cd/users/mydirectory
get -nopermissions -nopreservetime "myfile.txt" "C:\Users\Desktop\myfile.txt"
Close
exit
```

Then in Execute Process Task:

Executable: I have it pointing to WinSCP
Arguments: "/script=pathwaytomyscript"
WorkingDirectory: placeIwanttodropmyfile
SuccessValue: 1

That's everything I have. The process executes and gives me a green check mark but the file is not present. Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you can have an idea by these guide

[How to Use SFTP within SSIS](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/677002/How-to-Use-SFTP-within-SSIS)

[SFTP with SSIS Packages](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23740/SFTP-with-SSIS-Packages)

[Using sFTP in SQL Server SSIS](http://gregcaporale.wordpress.com/2012/02/23/using-sftp-in-sql-server-ssis/)